# Codeigniter Need help about session. select the name of logged in account and insert it into database

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, select, insert

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Array to string conversion

Filename: models/event_models.php

Line Number: 524

Backtrace:

File: D:\Xampp\htdocs\CapstoneFiles\application\models\event_models.php
Line: 524
Function: _error_handler

File: D:\Xampp\htdocs\CapstoneFiles\application\models\event_models.php
Line: 536
Function: getuserinfo

File: D:\Xampp\htdocs\CapstoneFiles\application\controllers\event_user.php
Line: 30
Function: join_events

File: D:\Xampp\htdocs\CapstoneFiles\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'

select * from user_profile where user_id=Array

Filename: D:/Xampp/htdocs/CapstoneFiles/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691`

```
public function getuserinfo($user_id) {
    $userdata = $this->session->userdata('user_id');

    //This is Model

    $userid = $this->db->escape_str($user_id);
    $sql = "select * from user_profile where user_id=".$userid;
    return $this->db->query($sql);
}

public function join_events($event_id) {
    $data = array(
        'participants_id' => "",  
        'event_id' => $event_id,
        'profile_id' => $this->event_models->getuserinfo($this->session->user_id)- 
        >row()->name
    );
    $this->db->insert('participants',$data);
}
```

Comment: print the data $userid = $this->db->escape_str($user_id); print_r($userid); exit; then check

Answer (score 0):

The variable `$userid` is not a integer variable, its an array. Just make sure you are passing a integer variable. It should work.

Try the following

```
$sql = "select * from user_profile where user_id=".$user_id;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: How can i do that sir?

Answer (score 0):

> You are getting the session data in one variable and  passing another variable

```
$sql = "select * from user_profile where user_id=".$userdata;
```

> update the query like this

Comment: tnx sir i will try

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: user_id

Filename: controllers/event_user.php

Line Number: 31

Backtrace:

File: D:\Xampp\htdocs\CapstoneFiles\application\controllers\event_user.php
Line: 31
Function: _error_handler

File: D:\Xampp\htdocs\CapstoneFiles\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once